# IIS custom http error pages work with HTTP, but not with HTTPS

Tags: http, iis, https

I implemented custom http error pages for a website I'm working on. But I did this not on the website level - The requirement was to do this on the server level. So basically, I changed the files from DRIVE:\inetpub\custerr\ so that they display my custom errors and not the IIS specific ones. Additionally in the web.config file of my website I added the following line in the /configuration/system.webServer section:

```
<httpErrors existingResponse="Replace" />
```

I did this to prevent certain errors I encountered. OK, we're through with the background info.

**The problem**

When I access the server page that doesn't exists through HTTP (like [IP_ADDRESS]/non_existent_page.aspx) I get 403 custom error page, which is fine. However, when I access the same page through HTTPS, I get the following IIS (or rather ASP.NET) error:

[image]

**Is there any way to make the server display my custom error page in this case?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I had to add the attribute below to the system.webServer/httpErrors element of the applicationHost.config file

```
existingResponse="Replace"
```

I did this using the script below:

```
C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set config /section:system.webServer/httpErrors /existingResponse:Replace /commit:apphost
```